# MySQL: Как определить изменение данных за 24 часа?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Поскажите, есть запись в БД для статей, где учитывается количество лайков. Скажем у одной из статей 25 лайков было вчера всего. К концу сегодняшнего дня количество лайков увеличилось до 33. Как узнать через запрос, на сколько лайков был увеличена запись в БД сегодня?

Comment: Где-нибудь записать, сколько было вчера, подождать сутки, посмотреть, сколько стало сегодня и вычесть новое значение из старого записанного

Comment: @andreymal а как сделать, чтобы запись создавалась автоматически в 23:55?

Comment: Взять любой инструмент, который умеет запускать программы по расписанию, например cron, а в программе написать что вам угодно

Comment: а одним запросом это никак не сделать? Всмысле, без фиксирования числа за день и записи значения отдельно.

Comment: Как вы представляете себе получение разницы двух чисел, если в базе хранится всего одно число?

Comment: Думал, что есть какие-то внутренние запросы или команды mysql чтобы следить за динамикой, но вижу, что это не так. Спасибо!

Comment: Сделайте в базе триггер на обновление количества лайков, который при смене даты будет записывать старое значение куда-то ещё. А ещё проще, сделайте табличку учета лайков со столбцами: id статьи, дата, количество лайков. При прилёте нового лайка увеличиваете запись, где совпадает id статьи и дата. При отсутствии совпадения - создаёте новую запись

Comment: Вообще, если лайки хранятся как отдельные записи, а не одно число, то можно просто фильтровать их по нужному диапазону времени.